# first div expanding beyond specified size?

Tags: css

have four items that just show a bg image until you hove and then it displays text, bg image is then set to none.

The first element is expanding beyond the height of the other three. I really just wanted them all to stay at 200x200px. All the images used for backgrounds are 200x200px.

Should the .p1top be positioned differently such as absolute?

```
.p1top {
    height:200px;
    margin-left:45px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(protect.png);
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:transparent;
    line-height: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.p1top :hover {
    height:200px !important;
    width:200px;
    background-image:none;
    background-color:#7D8093;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.p2top :hover {
    width:200px;
    background-image:none;
    background-color:#7D8093;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.p2top {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(build.png);
    float:left;
    margin-left:-15px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:transparent;
    line-height: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
/*.p2top :hover {width:200px; background-color:#7D8093;line-height: 20px; color: #FFFFFF; }*/
 .p3top {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(savebg.png);
    margin-left: -20px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:transparent;
    line-height: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.p3top :hover {
    width:200px;
    background-color:#7D8093;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.p4top {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(help.png);
    margin-left: -20px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:transparent;
    line-height: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.p4top :hover {
    width:200px;
    background-color:#7D8093;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Post your HTML since your CSS can apply to many types of layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the height only in `.p1top` but not in other divs, so you need to set that's div height also. Then you could define position such as absolute but for this you should wrap all of these div with a div positioned relatively. If you post a jsfiddle that would be very much sensible.